# Install AAPANEL but the main site doesn't load

Tags: server, lubuntu, apache2, iptables, firewall

I installed aaPanel, but it keeps on timing out.

Here's the output:

```
The connection timed out and the CA server was unable to access your website!
Verify domain name:hostexodus.co.za
Verify URL:Click to view
Verify content:MrY5xni6rbPLDSdDFnsatSrSXV61Q2HHgKrCaKh5zGU
Error code:185.193.17.130: Fetching https://hostexodus.co.za/.well-known/acme-challenge/MrY5xni6rbPLDSdDFnsatSrSXV61Q2HHgKrCaKh5zGU: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)
Verify results: Verify failed
```

I did this, but the connection still times out.

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```